# What does this notation mean? Eigenvectors and Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[image]

I am trying to solve this question but I couldn't understand what does $A(v_1+v_2)$ mean.

Could anybody help me with this? Thanks...

Comment: The matrix $A$ times the vector $v_1+v_2$.

Comment: People are using the language times, multiplied and product... these are all correct but it might be good to see matrices as functions and that $A(v_1+v_2)$ is just like $f(x_1+x_2)$ for some function $f$ on some space with addition.

Answer (score 3):

As $v_1, v_2 \in \mathbb{R}^2$, $v_1 + v_2 \in \mathbb{R}^2$, so $A(v_1 + v_2)$ is just the product of the matrix $A$ and the vector $v_1 + v_2$.

Comment: Oh, was it that simple? :) thank you.

Answer (score 3):

because  $v_i$ is eigenvector and $\lambda_i$ is eigenvalue that means that

$A*v_1=\lambda_1*v_1$

$A*v_2=\lambda_2*v_2$

also please pay attention that $A(v_1+v_2)=A*v_1+A*v_2$

could you continue?just insert values

Comment: Yes I've solved it thanks very much!